# Applet embed tag is returning ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, html, google-chrome, applet, classnotfoundexception

I have an applet jar file `cia.jar` and the class in it `main.class` and I have my class in the package `com.gmail.connorbphtml.WebApp`.  I am trying to embed my applet into a webpage. When I am trying to do this I get a class not found error.

The applet works fine in Eclipse but then when I try to embed it it does not work.

Here is my HTML using embed:

```
<embed code="main.class"
archive="cia.jar"
width="200" height="200"
type="application/x-java-applet;version=1.6.0"
pluginspage="http://java.sun.com/javase/downloads"/>
```

I have been having this problem for months which made me give up applets because  I can't get this working.

Does anyone know what went wrong?

The results from `jar -tvf cia.jar` are:

```
39 Sun Sep 16 12:34:50 EDT 2012 META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
     0 Sat Sep 15 18:02:30 EDT 2012 com/
     0 Sat Sep 15 18:02:30 EDT 2012 com/gmail/
     0 Sat Sep 15 18:02:30 EDT 2012 com/gmail/connorbphtml/
     0 Sat Sep 15 18:02:30 EDT 2012 com/gmail/connorbphtml/WebApp/
   136 Sat Sep 15 18:02:16 EDT 2012 com/gmail/connorbphtml/WebApp/package-info.class
   692 Sat Sep 15 23:26:08 EDT 2012 com/gmail/connorbphtml/WebApp/main.class
   226 Sat Sep 15 18:01:20 EDT 2012 .classpath
   366 Sat Sep 15 18:01:20 EDT 2012 .project
```

The error in the console:

```
Java Plug-in 1.6.0_33
Using JRE version 1.6.0_33-b03-424-11M3720 Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM
User home directory = /Users/Connor

----------------------------------------------------
c:   clear console window
f:   finalize objects on finalization queue
g:   garbage collect
h:   display this help message
l:   dump classloader list
m:   print memory usage
o:   trigger logging
q:   hide console
r:   reload policy configuration
s:   dump system and deployment properties
t:   dump thread list
v:   dump thread stack
x:   clear classloader cache
0-5: set trace level to <n>
----------------------------------------------------

Java Plug-in 1.6.0_33
Using JRE version 1.6.0_33-b03-424-11M3720 Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM
User home directory = /Users/Connorload: class Sun_Microsystems_Java_Security_Update_6.class not found.
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Sun_Microsystems_Java_Security_Update_6.class
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Applet2ClassLoader.findClass(Applet2ClassLoader.java:252)
load: class com/gmail/connorbphtml/WebApp/main.class not found.
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass0(Plugin2ClassLoader.java:249)
load: class com/gmail/connorbphtml/WebApp/main.class not found.
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Plugin2ClassLoader.java:179)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Plugin2ClassLoader.java:160)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadCode(Plugin2ClassLoader.java:690)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager.createApplet(Plugin2Manager.java:3045)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager$AppletExecutionRunnable.run(Plugin2Manager.java:1497)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
Exception: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Sun_Microsystems_Java_Security_Update_6.class
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.gmail.connorbphtml.WebApp.main.class
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Applet2ClassLoader.findClass(Applet2ClassLoader.java:252)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass0(Plugin2ClassLoader.java:249)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Plugin2ClassLoader.java:179)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Plugin2ClassLoader.java:160)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadCode(Plugin2ClassLoader.java:690)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager.createApplet(Plugin2Manager.java:3045)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager$AppletExecutionRunnable.run(Plugin2Manager.java:1497)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
Exception: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.gmail.connorbphtml.WebApp.main.class
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.gmail.connorbphtml.WebApp.main.class
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Applet2ClassLoader.findClass(Applet2ClassLoader.java:252)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass0(Plugin2ClassLoader.java:249)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Plugin2ClassLoader.java:179)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Plugin2ClassLoader.java:160)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadCode(Plugin2ClassLoader.java:690)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager.createApplet(Plugin2Manager.java:3045)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager$AppletExecutionRunnable.run(Plugin2Manager.java:1497)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
Exception: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.gmail.connorbphtml.WebApp.main.class
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `deployJava.js` to [write the element for the applet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/deployment_advice.html#deployingApplets).

E.G. adapted from the page:

```
<script src="http://www.java.com/js/deployJava.js"></script>
<script>
    var attributes = {codebase:'.',
                      code:'com.gmail.connorbphtml.WebApp.main',
                      archive:'cia.jar',
                      width:200, height:200};
    var version = '1.6';
    deployJava.runApplet(attributes, parameters, version);
</script>
```

The script will write the appropriate element in the correct form for the browser/OS on which it is running.

Comment: I tried this, but with this i am getting a completely blank page instead.

Comment: 1) There is nothing wrong with using the applet element while working out the paths. 2) Usually there is more information available on failed launches.  Ensure the [Java Console](http://www.java.com/en/download/help/javaconsole.xml) 3) To give best help on solving this, we need more information on the directory structure of the server, the structure of the Jar, and the package/code statements in the source.

Comment: i am running an html file on my desktop with the jar file also on my desktop. and in the src of the applet i have the package com.gmail.connorbphtml.WebApp and then i have the main class: main.class which is inside my package. and i made the project in Eclipse.

Comment: What is the content of the Java Console? I meant to add before *" Ensure the Java Console.."* **is visible.** Does the code ever `catch(Exception e)` but fail to `e.printStackTrace()`?  If so, change it, recompile, build the jar, *flush the class-cache* from the console & F5 to refresh the page.  Please edit a directory listing of the desktop directory into the question, as well as a `jar -tvf cia.jar`.

Comment: OK, could you go to testing with a simple `applet` element in HTML and edit the HTML into the question?

Comment: BTW - `Sun_Microsystems_Java_Security_Update_6.class not found`  That class is not in the J2SE and not in the Jar.  Where is it?

Answer (score 0):

Code should not contain `.class` extension. Try this.

```
<applet code="com.gmail.connorbphtml.WebApp.main" archive="cia.jar"
width="200" height="200"></applet>
```

Also you did not include the `package` name in the `code` attribute.

Comment: The only problem with using the applet tag is that it has been deprecated in the modern browsers like Chrome, FireFox and Safari

Comment: and i still got the class not found error using that code just now.

Comment: try posting your exception here