# Java application in <embed> tag

Tags: java, html, applet

I'm trying to embed a java application in HTML `embed` tag like below, but it won't work:

```
<embed src="Java2DGame.jar" code="ca.vanzeben.game.GameLauncher"
  width="480" height="360"
  type="application/x-java-applet;version=1.7.0"
  pluginspage="http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.7.0/download.html"/>
```

But it works fine in `applet` tag like so :

```
<applet code="ca.vanzeben.game.GameLauncher" 
archive="Java2DGame.jar" width="480" height="360"></applet>
```

Please tell me what am i missing ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `object` tag instead:

```
<object width="480" height="360" data="Java2DGame.jar" type="application/x-java-applet">
    <param name="codebase" value="http://yourdomain.com/path/to/codebase/" />
    <param name="code" value="ca.vanzeben.game.GameLauncher" />
    <param name="width" value="480" />
    <param name="height" value="360" />
    <param name="archive" value="Java2DGame.jar" />
</object>
```

You shouldn't use the `embed` tag for applets because it doesn't seem to be complying with any standard, and doesn't seem like there is a way to specify an archive for it.

The recommended way to include an applet in a webpage seem to be the use of `deployJava.js`, as specified in Andrew Thompson answer to another question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12444699/1055284

Answer (score 0):

Note: The HTML specification states that the applet tag is deprecated, and that you should use the object tag instead. However, the specification is vague about how browsers should implement the object tag to support Java applets, and browser support is currently inconsistent. Oracle therefore recommends that you continue to use the applet tag as a consistent way to deploy Java applets across browsers on all platforms.

The following is the syntax for the applet tag. Required attributes are in bold. Optional attributes are in regular typeface. Values you specify are in italics:

```
<applet
    codebase = codebaseURL
    archive = archiveList
    code = appletFile ...or...  object = serializedApplet
    alt = alternateText
    name = appletInstanceName
    width = pixels
    height = pixels
    align = alignment
    vspace = pixels
    hspace = pixels
    legacy_lifestyle = boolean
>
<param name = appletAttribute1 value = value1>
<param name = appletAttribute2 value = value2>
...
alternateHTML
</applet>
```

Comment: As i said, my problem is not about `applet` tag. I need to use `embed` tag